# User with UID 0 problem

Tags: sudo, uid

I am running into an issue with Redhat 6.7. We installed a piece of software that created a user `admin` with uid of 0. This is a turnkey install of the software so I am really unable to change the uid.

The problem is now if I do a `sudo -i` from my account, it randomly takes me to either root or this new user. Sometimes it says `root@hostname#` and sometimes `admin@hostname`. The problem it creates is when I try to run certain commands it complains that I have to be root to run the command and I am unable to execute those commands from `admin@hostname` and I can't get to `root@hostname` consistently.

Is there a way to configure the system such that `sudo -i` goes to root user only?

Comment: Did you tried `sudo -u admin` or `sudo -u root` ? What are the two lines corresponding to those accounts in your /etc/passwd file ? Generally you can't change the root UID (it must be 0) but you can change the login and set it up to admin (but various other apps can complain)

Comment: sudo -u root or sudo -u admin both just show me that the sudo usage, so basically sudo is not liking the command. Here are the two entries from passwd.......root:x:0:0:,,,:/root:/bin/bash
cliadmin:x:0:0::/home/cliadmin:/opt/vormetric/coreguard/server/bin/clish

Comment: strange because if you look this: https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html it's a legitimate option

Comment: If both accounts have the same uid, they are the same account. The process that checks for root is using a flimsy algorithm.

Comment: Both your `sudo` implementation and these other applications that complain about not being root are buggy.   The former is buggy because it should always log you in as root. You should report this to redhat.  Whatever other applications complain that you need to be root are also buggy and you should report them.  They should not care about $USER and only be looking at the fact that they are running as UID=0.  Also this "turn key" application should not be creating a backdoor root account.

Answer (score 1):

Both accounts are root (they might have different groups, however). Use `sudo -u root` or `sudo -u bogus` as required.

I'd suggest you check carefully how this is installed, perhaps the UID 0 got picked by mistake? Perhaps it got specified as the "unused" account to own the service? Running ***any*** not carefully vetted for security software by default as root, or even worse have `root` exposed to the network as a service is a ***very, very bad idea***.

I'd look carefully into the software, and start considering alternatives. If this gets done by mistake or on purpose when installing is a big, waving red flag. Who knows what else they screwed up, where you can't see it...